# Hilbert space and uncountable cardinal

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, cardinals

Given an uncountable cardinal does there exist Hilbert space with orthonormal basis of that cardinality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\kappa$ be any cardinal. Define $\ell^2(\kappa)$ as follows: As a set, we have 
$$ \ell^2(\kappa) := \left\{x \colon \kappa \to \mathbf K \Biggm| \sum_{i \in \kappa} |x(i)|^2 < \infty \right\} $$
With the scalar product
$$ (x,y) := \sum_{i \in \kappa} x(i)\overline{y(i)} $$
$\ell^2(\kappa)$ is a Hilbert space, of which the maps $e^i$, $i \in \kappa$, given by $e^i(j) = \delta_{ij}$, $j \in \kappa$ form an orthonormal basis of cardinality $\kappa$.

Comment: Given any cardinal can we define a vector space with Hamel basis of that cardinality?

Comment: You should ask this as a seperate question, but the answer is yes. Consider 
$$ \mathbf K^{(\kappa)} := \left\{ x \colon \kappa \to \mathbf K \biggm| x^{-1}[\mathbf K \setminus \{0\}] \text{ is finite} \right\} $$
this space has $e^i$, $i \in \kappa$ (defined as above) as basis.